# insert data into two different tables using Linq

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ASP .net framsework 4.5 MVC4

I have two different tables as follows

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdateTime { get; set; }

    public virtual List<ProductVariants> ProductVariants { get; set; } 
}

public class ProductVariants
{
    public int ProductVariantsID { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    public string FrontImage { get; set; }
    public string BackImage { get; set; }

    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

I am using following code to submit data into these table at one time.

```
Product product = new Product
            {
                Name = model.Product.Name,

                Description = model.Product.Description,
                CreateTime = DateTime.Now,
                LastUpdateTime = DateTime.Now,
            };

            ProductVariants pv = new ProductVariants
            {
                FrontImage = model.FrontImage.FileName,
                BackImage = model.BackImage.FileName,
                Color = model.ProductVariants.Color,
            };

            product.ProductVariants.Add(pv);
            dbcontext.Products.Add(product);
            dbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

What I am doing wrong ?? Do I have to Submit ProductVariants too as:

```
  dbcontext.ProductsVariants.Add(pv);
```

If yes then how I am going to add ProductVariants Value in Product as virtual .. ?

Please Help !!!

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted? Do you see any errors? Is one of the entities not correctly inserted?

Comment: I am getting System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
on product.ProductVariants.Add(pv);

Comment: Actually I am new to ASP.net dnt have much idea how exactly the code should be to insert data in multiple tables ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the property, `ProductVariants`, is not correctly intialized. Normally, you'd have to provide it with an initial value (e.g. in the `Product` constructor).

However, it looks like you're using Entity Framework and Code First development. If this is indeed the case, instead of declaring your property as a `List<T>` use an `ICollection<T>`:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdateTime { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductVariants> ProductVariants { get; set; } 
}
```

This allows Entity Framework to automatically wire up the property with an appropriate implementation of `ICollection<T>` (rather than a basic `List<T>`).

Also, you probably need to create your entities using the [`Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696460%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method rather than directly constructing new instances:

```
Product product = dbcontext.Products.Create();
product.Name = model.Product.Name;
...

ProductVariants pv = dbcontext.ProductVariants.Create(); 
pv.FrontImage = model.FrontImage.FileName;
...

product.ProductVariants.Add(pv);
dbcontext.Products.Add(product);
dbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Yes I am using Code First Entity Frame Work. 
I just tried ICollection<ProductVariants> instead of List<ProductVariants>. But still getting same exception.

Comment: @Inder Sorry, I forgot to mention using `DbSet.Create` rather than directly constructing entities. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank You sooo Much for your time and effort .

Here s How I got it solved ..

      List<ProductVariants> pvlist = new List<ProductVariants>();
                pvlist.Add(pv);

                product.ProductVariants = pvlist;
                dbcontext.Products.Add(product);
                dbcontext.SaveChanges();